# How to link docker containers?

Tags: docker

I have tried linking my docker containers but it seems to give error on access.

My structure is as following:

1. Database docker(Mysql) - Container name  is `um-mysql`
2. Back-end docker(Tomcat) - Image name is `cz-um-app`
3. Front-end docker(Nginx) - Image name is `cz-um-frontend`

Linking of Back-end with Database docker is done as following and it works perfectly:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --name backendservices --link um-mysql:um-mysql cz-um-app
```

The linking of Front-end with Back-end is done as following:

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 --name frontend --link backendservices:backendservices cz-um-frontend
```

But, linking of Front-end with Back-end is not working.

I have a login page, on submit, it accesses a url `http://backendservices:8080/MyApp`

In console, it shows error as:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Not sure why linking of back-end container with database works fine and not the same case of front-end with back-end. **Do I need to configure some settings in Nginx for this?**

The hosts entry is as following and I am able to ping backendservices too:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the question, yet for setting up dev stacks, I strongly recommend using `docker-compose`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: What output does `docker logs backendservices` give? Which further steps have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: I checked logs of backendservices, but there is no log entry as request has not reached till backendservices container. I have updated the question with Hosts entry snapshot and verified the backendservices by pinging them. Any configuration needed in Nginx conf by any chance?

Comment: I'm reading a very interesting manual about Docker. I know `--link` is deprecated hence I fail to find the syntax of this command. Does the syntax is  `--link container1:container2` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to map 8080:8080 for `backendservices`: any [`EXPOSE`d](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) port in `backendservices` image is visible by any other container linked to it. No host port mapping needed.

Secondly, you can check in your front end if the backend has been register:

```
docker exec -it frontend bash
cat /etc/hosts
```

If it is not, check `docker ps -a` to see if backend is still runnong.