# Access local host ports from docker container

Tags: docker

I am using Landoop fast data dev and exposing ports -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082  -p 9092:9092 of the container.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 
 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 --name=containerA landoop/fast-data-dev
```

These are accessible when I use on the host machine via localhost. 
But when I run another container using

`docker run -it --rm --net=host --name containerB mytest/containerB`.

1) How do I access the above exposed ports of containerA from containerB?
I do realise for MAC we have to use `docker.for.mac.localhost` instead of localhost. How do i confirm these ports are accesible from docker.for.mac.localhost ie containerB ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264349/how-to-link-docker-containers)

Comment: I have read the above post as well but thats not exactly my case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get two different containers working together I'd use docker-compose to create a virtual network between them

Official docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Answer (score 1):

For containers to be able to communicate, they need to share a virtual network.

```
docker network create my-net

docker run --rm -it --network my-net -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 9092:9092\
 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 --name=containerA landoop/fast-data-dev

docker run -it --rm  --network my-net --name containerB mytest/containerB
```

Now containerB can communicate with containerA using `http://containerA:<port>`

Comment: I tried that but its not working for me. Also i can give it a try 1 more time but how do i validate those exposed ports are available on the container B ?

Comment: For communication between containers you don&#39;t need to map host ports to container ports.

Answer (score 0):

At https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-connectors-tests you can see how multiple dockers are composed together i.e. `fast-data-dev` + `elastic-search` in order to run integration tests by generating data onto Kafka and then run the https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor Kafka connectors to write data to elastic-search and so on.

The results of the integration tests are published at:

http://coyote.landoop.com/connect/

Comment: Thanks but I couldn’t find one for jdbc and I am working on jdbc connector docker container